How to properly intialize a PHP array to satisfy Stripe payment line_items syntax
In Javascript, I built a string to mimic the structure of Stripe payment "line_items" (there may be between 1 and 4 items). I then pass that string to my checkout.php file (as an URL parameter), where I set up the Stripe\Checkout\Session.
In order to use the incoming "live" purchases (name and unit_amount) I create and array from the incoming string, and use that as the "line_items" value in the Stripe call. I have a test array ($zarray) that I setup to mimic the anticipated purchases from javascript. When I use $zarray in the parameter list all is well, the hosted payment form comes up and life is good. When I use the incoming string to create a new array $xarray ($xarray=array($purchaseData['purchased'])).
I'd expected it to be accepted by the Stripe parameter validation, but it fails ("This page isn't working" along with notice of "invalid object"). So I compared the two PHP arrays by printing them with print_r() and was surprised to see how different they were. The prefab array $zarray was built from the same format text string, but the output of print_r() is certainly different:

My question is: how to I properly form/use a text initialization string to pass to PHP such that the line_items value in PHP faithfully mimics what you'd get if the whole inline description were used?
I was expecting my on-the-fly array to pass muster and be accepted by Stripe API (it's not). As I described, I built server-side test array that works, but my imported initialization data is yielding an error. I'm including the PHP code and a comparison between $xarray and $zarray - the difference is obvious. I realize that there are different syntax options for this, I'm just unclear as to how to properly form my incoming text to pass the Stripe validation.
<?php

require_once  "vendor/autoload.php";
require __DIR__ . "/config.php";

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(STRIPE_KEY);
    $zarray=array([ [ "quantity" => 1, "price_data" => [ "currency" => "usd", "unit_amount" => 15000,"product_data" => [ "name" => "small child jumping over waves in ocean" ] ] ], [ "quantity" => 1, "price_data" => [ "currency" => "usd", "unit_amount" => 18500,"product_data" => [ "name" => "collage of flowers on green grass" ] ] ], [ "quantity" => 1, "price_data" => [ "currency" => "usd", "unit_amount" => 20000,"product_data" => [ "name" => "collage of Lincoln Monument" ] ] ], [ "quantity" => 1, "price_data" => [ "currency" => "usd", "unit_amount" => 25000,"product_data" => [ "name" => "collage of Martin Luther King Monument with quote" ] ] ] ]);

$query_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
parse_str($query_string,$purchaseData);
$xarray=array($purchaseData['purchased']);

# this is my debug output that made me realize format of the two "identical" array just weren't the same.
echo "array from checkout page";
print_r($xarray);
echo "Local Array ". PHP_EOL;
print_r($zarray);

$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    "mode" => "payment",
    "success_url" => "success.php",
    "cancel_url" => "checkout.htm",
    "locale" => "auto",
    "phone_number_collection" => ['enabled' => 'true'],
    "shipping_address_collection" => [ 'allowed_countries' => ['US','CA']],
    "line_items"=>$xarray << using $xarry fails, using $zarray works
    ]);

http_response_code(303);
error_log($checkout_session->url);
header("Location: " . $checkout_session->url);


Requested var_export of the two differing arrays:
This is $xarray var_export:
array (
  0 => '[ [ "quantity" => 1, "price_data" => [ "currency" => "usd", "unit_amount" => 15000,"product_data" => [ "name" => "small child jumping over waves in ocean" ] ] ], [ "quantity" => 1, "price_data" => [ "currency" => "usd", "unit_amount" => 18500,"product_data" => [ "name" => "collage of flowers on green grass" ] ] ], [ "quantity" => 1, "price_data" => [ "currency" => "usd", "unit_amount" => 20000,"product_data" => [ "name" => "collage of Lincoln Monument" ] ] ], [ "quantity" => 1, "price_data" => [ "currency" => "usd", "unit_amount" => 25000,"product_data" => [ "name" => "collage of Martin Luther King Monument with quote" ] ] ] ]',
)

This is $zarray var_export:
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'quantity' => 1,
      'price_data' => 
      array (
        'currency' => 'usd',
        'unit_amount' => 15000,
        'product_data' => 
        array (
          'name' => 'small child jumping over waves in ocean',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'quantity' => 1,
      'price_data' => 
      array (
        'currency' => 'usd',
        'unit_amount' => 18500,
        'product_data' => 
        array (
          'name' => 'collage of flowers on green grass',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'quantity' => 1,
      'price_data' => 
      array (
        'currency' => 'usd',
        'unit_amount' => 20000,
        'product_data' => 
        array (
          'name' => 'collage of Lincoln Monument',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'quantity' => 1,
      'price_data' => 
      array (
        'currency' => 'usd',
        'unit_amount' => 25000,
        'product_data' => 
        array (
          'name' => 'collage of Martin Luther King Monument with quote',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)


Use var_export() to output an executable version of $xarray and $zarray and post the results here as text. It's impossible to read the image version because of the syntax differences and syntax highlighting.

Doesn't "array from checkout page " is Array([0] => an_array_of_associated_array), while "Local Array" is Array([0] => an_associated_array)?

var_export added to original question

on first blush it DOES appear that $xarray is an array and $zarray is an array of arrays, how would I properly initialize $xarray if that's the case? The brackets in the list_items mimics the actual examples provided by Stripe. Pardon my ignorance.

Since I really needed to get this operational, I changed my approach. Rather than meticulously coding an initialization string in javascript, sending that to PHP page and expecting to use that string as the array initialization, I just passed the line_item details (price, quantity, name, etc) and parse THAT in a PHP function: actually building the native line_items array. It works, all is well. What did I learn? Use the target (in this case PHP) environment to do the heavy lifting, just pass variable data from javascript

This answer would be improved if you showed the actual code. It's hard to understand from this vague description.
